# My app keeps crashing then not starting up again, with a bad access error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

The thing that's doing it shouldn't cause that to happen. What also comes with the error is this, however:

Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib

Is this something which would affect my app on the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you get is because the debugger can't find information it needs to debug; it's not a problem with your app. Apple will obviously care about the crash, though.